# How to delete GUI elements with .destroy() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

Im new to python and im trying to do a simple program with Tkinter. I want to delete the GUI element "Error" and "passwordText". But I'm not sure how to do it. I would love to get some help with it, thanks for reading!

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import string
import random


window = Tk()
window.title("Password Generator")
window.configure(background="white")

def click():
    global length
    length = textEntry.get()
    start()

def start():
    global length
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    digits = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation


    all = lower + upper + digits + symbols
    try:
        global randomPass
        randomPass = random.sample(all, int(length))

        password = "".join(randomPass)
        global passwordText
        passwordText = Label (window, text=password, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        return
    except:
        error = Label (window, text="Error, please try another length", bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)




textEntry = Entry(window, width=60, bg="white")
textEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

Button(window, text="Submit Length", width=13, command=click) .grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the error widget, just use `error.destroy()`.